$\nu^-(E) \geq - \operatorname {inf} \{\nu (F): F\in \mathcal{M}, F \subset E \}.$
Suppose that $\nu$ is a signed measure on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ and $E \in \mathcal{M}.$
$(a) \nu^-(E) = -\inf \{\nu (F): F\in \mathcal{M}, F \subset E \}.$
I was solving the following part   $\nu^-(E) \geq - \operatorname {inf} \{\nu (F): F\in \mathcal{M}, F \subset E \}.$
And here are my steps:
If $F \subset E,$ then $F \cap N \subset E \cap N,$ hence $$\nu (F) \geq\nu(F \cap N) =  \nu^{-}(F) \geq - \nu^{-}(E)$$
And hence $\nu(F)\geq - \nu^{-}(E)$ but then how can I complete? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Since we have $\nu^-(E)\geq -\nu(F),\,\forall F \subset E,F \in \mathscr{M}$ then
$$\begin{aligned}\nu^-(E)&\geq \sup\{-\nu(F):F\subset E,F \in \mathscr{M}\}\\
&=-\inf\{\nu(F):F\subset E,F \in \mathscr{M}\}
\end{aligned}$$
